# String and Final

Tags: java, string, variables, final

What is difference between in the following statements

```
String name = "Tiger";

final String name ="Tiger";
```

Although the `String` class is `final` class, why do we need to create a String "CONSTANT" variable as final?

Comment: It is the reference to the string which is made final here, not the String itself.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`final` in this context means that the variable `name` can only be assigned once. Assigning a different `String` object to it again results in a compile error.

I think the source of the confusion here is that the `final` keyword can be used in several different contexts:

- final class: The class cannot be subclassed.
- final method: The method cannot be overridden.
- final variable: The variable can only be assigned once.

See the Wikipedia article on [final in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)) for examples on each case.

Comment: Remember 'final' is also about safe publication to other threads, though (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

"final" means different things in the two cases.

The java.lang.String class is final. This means you can't inherit from it.

The variable "name" is final, meaning that you can't change it to point to a different instance of String. So a non-final String variable isn't a constant, because you could read it at two different times and get different values.

As it happens, Java string objects are also immutable. This means that you cannot modify the value which a particular String object represents. Compare this with an array - you can replace the first element of an array object with a different object, but you can't replace the first character of a String object with a different char. This is why String.replace() returns a new string - it can't modify the old one.

One reason that String is final is to prevent an instance of a subclass of String, which implements mutable behaviour, being passed in place of a String.

But whether you can modify a particular object, and whether you can assign a different object to a variable, are completely different concepts. One is a property of String objects, and the other is a property of String variables, which are references to String objects.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that [Java final keyword](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml) serves two purposes in this case:

- it means the reference cannot be set to another String-- i.e. you cannot subsequently do "name = ...";
- but crucially, it means that the reference is **correctly published to other threads** (see linked article for more details, or works such as Goetz et al, "Java Concurrency in Practice".

Comment: Yup, the semantics of final is very important in concurrency applications, not so in normal Java applications, because Java programmers tends to embrace mutability.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing immutable with final.

String, like Integer and Long, is an immutable class in that the internal data is protected from modification through encapsulation.

However, like Ayman said, final refers to the pointer to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [The final word on the final keyword](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/final-keyword.shtml).

```
String name = "scott";
name = "tiger"; // OK

final String gender = "male";
gender = "female"; // won't compile you cannot reassign gender cause it's final
```

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is marked as **final** then the value of that variable cannot be changed i.e **final keyword when used with a variable makes it a constant.** And if you try to change the value of that variable during the course of your program the compiler will give you an error.

**NOTE :**
             *If you mark variable of a reference type as final, that variable cannot refer to any other object. However, you can change the object's contents, because only the reference itself is final.*

SOURCE : [Final Keyword in Java](http://www.code2learn.com/2011/12/final-keyword-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

To deduce that String objects are Final by default is in itself a vague statement. The basics of Java dictate that if an instance variable is not pointing to a memory location it becomes eligible for Garbage collection. The same thing happens with the String objects. They are immutable but their references can be changed. To overcome this we can use "Final String s1 = "Final String" " the final keyword won't allow any assignment to s1 except at the time of First Declaration, making it truly immutable.

```
public class DemoStringF 
{
    String s1; //Declaring an Instance Variable to type String. 

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        DemoStringF d = new DemoStringF ();
        d.s1 = "Intializing s1 here"; //Initializing the s1

          System.out.println("Value ref. by s1 is " +d.s1); //Displays the String 
                                                            by which s1 is 
                                                            initialized.

         System.out.println("Value of s1 is " +d.s1.hashCode()); //Displays the 
                                                                 value of the s1.

         d.s1 = d.s1.concat(" Adding String to s1"); //Changing the value ref. by 
                                                       s1.
        System.out.println("Value ref. by s1 after concat() is " +d.s1); 
                                                    //Displays a new value of s1.


        System.out.println("Value of s1 is " +d.s1.hashCode()); //Displays 
                                                            the value of the s1.
    }

    }
```

[image]