# Does it make sense to define a final String in Java?

Tags: java, string, final

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String and Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874978/string-and-final)

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html I can read that:

```
Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.
```

Does this mean that a `final String` does not really make sense in Java, in the sense that the `final` attribute is somehow redundant?

Comment: Declaring a *variable* final has nothing to do with Object you've assigned to it.

Comment: The `Object` itself is immutable, but the reference to it might be mutable.  Making it `final` makes the reference immutable as well.

Comment: Thanks for all answers and comments. Sorry for duplicating.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `String` object is immutable but what it is is actually a reference to a `String` object which could be changed.

For example:

```
String someString = "Lala";
```

You can reassign the value held by this variable (to make it reference a different string):

```
someString = "asdf";
```

However, with this:

```
final String someString = "Lala";
```

Then the above reassignment would not be possible and would result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 23):

`final` refers to the variable, not the object, so yes, it make sense.

e.g.

```
final String s = "s";
s = "a"; // illegal
```

Answer (score 6):

It makes sense. The `final` keyword prevents future assignments to the variable. The following would be an error in java:

```
final String x = "foo";
x = "bar" // error on this assignment
```

Answer (score 6):

References are final, Objects are not. You can define a mutable object as final and change state of it. What final ensures is that the reference you are using cannot ever point to another object again.

Comment: What I understand from this answer; Due to String is immutable, when we change its content, it will point another object. So, if a string is final then reassignment will not work. But in the case of StringBuffer, it is mutable then we can change its content. Is it right?